# Angular string binding not working with ControllerAs vm

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I've been trying to do a two-way bind to a string variable on the Controller. When the controller changes the string, it isn't updated right away. I have already run the debugger on it and I know that the variable vm.overlay.file is changed. But it isn't updated on the View... it only updates the next time the user clicks the button that fires the selectOverlayFile() and then it presents the previous value of vm.overlay.file

Here goes the code:

```
(function () {
angular
.module("myapp.settings")
.controller("SettingsController", SettingsController);

SettingsController.$inject = [];

function SettingsController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.overlay = {
        file: undefined,
        options: {
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
        }
    };
    vm.errorMessages = [];
    vm.selectOverlayFile = selectOverlayFile;
    vm.appMode = "photo";

    vm.appModes = ["gif-HD", "gif-video", "photo"];

    activate();

    function activate() {

    }

    function selectOverlayFile() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(successOverlay, errorOverlay, vm.overlay.options);
    }

    function successOverlay(imageUrl) {
        //If user has successfully selected a file
        vm.overlay.file = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageUrl;
    }

    function errorOverlay(message) {
        //If user couldn't select a file
        vm.errorMessages.push(message);
    }

  }
})();
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by 'controller changes the string'? how controller changes it? can you show that part of code?

Comment: I explained it poorly. The user clicks a button and fires the selectOverlayFile(). Which then calls one of it's callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours searching for the issue and testing various solutions. I finally found it. The issue was that when the navigator.camera.getPicture(successOverlay, errorOverlay, vm.overlay.options) calls the callback function, it is out of AngularJS scope. So we need to notify Angular to update binding from within these callbacks using $scope.$apply():

```
(function () {
angular
.module("myapp.settings")
.controller("SettingsController", SettingsController);

SettingsController.$inject = ["$scope"];

function SettingsController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.overlay = {
        file: undefined,
        options: {
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
        }
    };
    vm.errorMessages = [];
    vm.selectOverlayFile = selectOverlayFile;
    vm.appMode = "photo";

    vm.appModes = ["gif-HD", "gif-video", "photo"];

    activate();

    ///////////////////

    function activate() {

    }

    function selectOverlayFile() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(successOverlay, errorOverlay, vm.overlay.options);
    }

    function successOverlay(imageUrl) {
        //If user has successfully selected a file
        vm.overlay.file = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageUrl;
        $scope.$apply();
    }

    function errorOverlay(message) {
        //If user couldn't select a file
        vm.errorMessages.push(message);
        $scope.$apply();
    }

  }
})();
```